# Developing using CUDA on several computers, when only one has a GPU installed

Tags: cuda, gpu, remote-access, remote-debugging

I am a Java developer. To speed some of our algorithms, we have decided to try CUDA.

But the Issue is, currently we have only one server with GPU installed and 3 developers have to work on it (by transferring the file each time over ssh and compiling and running it over there). This obviously is a tedious process.

What I would like to know is: On my machine which does not have GPU, can I using NSight  work on CUDA by compiling and generating files locally. This can automatically be transferred to server to get the result.

If we can at least work on algorithm locally using NSight (or any other IDE) and not pure `vim` and then compile it to remove compile time errors, this would save quite some time.

Comment: Which OS do you use? I know under windows it's possible to start the `Nsight Monitor` from `Nsight Visual Studio Edition` on the server and than connects the one from your developer system with the server one. But under linux I'm not sure, there isn't a way that I know.

Comment: Server is Linux is. Client is is no constraint. Can you please give more into @hubs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Linux you can do remote debugging using Nsight Eclipse Edition as [documented here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/nsight-eclipse-edition-getting-started-guide/index.html#remote-debugging). This requires 5.5 or later. On Windows you need to start the Nsight monitor on the server and then just configure Nsight Visual Studio Edition to use the remote machine.